# What criterias should I use to determine if a new feature of my app should be a new area or a new app?

Tags: c#, architecture, asp.net-mvc, server

I'm building a ASP.NET MVC Core App. I would like to add 2 new features:

- A new area for Admins and
- An Web-API for restful services.

I was wondering if the Web-API and the Admin area should be new "[ASP.NET MVC  Areas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas)" in the same project or should I create a new project for the API and the Admin.

What criteria should I use to take this decision?

Answer (score 2):

When looking at something very similar, I looked at the ability to independently deploy each unit.

If each unit can be deployed completely separately, even living on separate servers, then it may make sense to have them as separate projects.  You can build and deploy each unit completely independently when there are bugs that need to be fixed.  This can provide some benefits if you wanted to have separate SLA's or release cycles.

If each unit is very dependent on each other to the point you cannot deploy them as separate units, a change in one requires a release on the other, then having them as separate projects will complicate the deployment process with out an associated gain.

Like a lot of things in tech the answer is "it depends" but looking at the way you are going to deploy things can help determine the right answer.

Comment: So . your criteria is if the projects can be deployed as separate units. right?

Comment: @DanielSantos not quite, its the first thing i look at.  Next is deployment and maintainability concerns